# How can I download summary info about my emails using e.g. fetchmail?

Tags: email, gmail, fetchmail

I am trying to clear out my GMail account and recover some space. I've already searched for large attachments, but it seems like there's a fair amount of "dust" which adds up to gigabytes.

I know Fetchmail exists and can be used to download emails, but can I use it or something similar to download summary information so it can be sorted and deleted later?

Ideally the procedure would be to have a list of all emails as tuples of

```
(id, parent id [for chains], to, from, subject, size, total attachment size)
```

This would be retrieved for every email, but none of the bodies or attachments would be downloaded. I could then query this arbitrarily and get a list of `id` numbers which I can submit for deletion.

Is there a way to do this?

I use Ubuntu and am comfortable with a command line.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a regular IMAP client:

- `mutt -f imaps://imap.gmail.com`
- `alpine -f {imap.gmail.com/ssl}`
- Claws, Thunderbird, etc.?

However, I'm not sure which of them actually show attachment sizes.